# How to link .рф domain to blogspot?

Tags: domains, blogger

I have a cyrillic domain `*.рф` and a blog `*.blogspot.com`.
Now I want to link my domain to blog. I followed this [official manual](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?answer=55373), but when I tried to put my domain name into blog preferences (at *Settings > Publishing*), it sais, that I gave invalid domain name. Punycode also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

There's probably no way to do it at the moment, since their algorithms to check for a valid domain name has not been updated. File a complaint directly with them.

On a side note: With a *.рф domain name you'll run into trouble like this for many years to come. All kind of validation scripts that worked for years will fail to work with these newfangled domain names. I can understand the desire of people from non-Latin countries to have localized domains, but IMHO it'll cause serious damage and confusion. 7bit ASCII is the way to go for the next 20 years.

Comment: +1 - I don't know if I agree with "cause damage and confusion" but the rest of your answer is absolutally correct